# How to make [Image] float center above the other div?

Tags: html, css, css-float

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snEKL.jpg)

1. I need to make the header being **[Float center]** above the **[Main page]**.
2. If the **[Main page]** was covered by the **[Header]** that was float how to make sure the article isn't covered by the header?
3. There's a **little space** above the header, and I have to remove it to be **no space** there.

I was do it for 2 hours, and nothing happens-_-')

### Code

```
.Image-header {
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:block;
}
.Page-background {
    text-align: center;
    background-position: top;
}
```

*I really appreciated every helping answer :)*

Comment: add width to holder or max-width if you have responsive design

Comment: It will be good if you add your html code also.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Put image in a div and set that div align center.
             OR
put image inside

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you posted, I suggest the following approach:

```
.Image-header {
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:block;
}

.Page-background {
  background-position: center top;
  margin-top: -50px; // arbitrary, to tune
  padding-top: 50px; // to fix article content, same as above
}
```

I also suggest that for `.Page-background` you use a `background-color` instead of a `background-image` and that you rename your classes following the BEM naming standards (`.header__image` and `.page__background`)